# Rule of inference in logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

There is a slide in my class notes that mention

$$
\neg p \rightarrow F_0
$$

therefore p.

It then follows up and it says

---

if we want to establish the validity of the argument

Eqn 1: ($p_0 \wedge p_1... \wedge p_n) $ -> q,

we can establish the validity of logically equivalent argument.

Eqn 2: ($p_0 \wedge p_1... \wedge p_n \wedge \neg q) -> F_0$

---

My questions:

1. The implication

$$
\neg p \rightarrow F_0
$$

leads to "therefore p" because p is assumed to be true and the only way p can lead to false is through negation of p? I'm very confused about this

2. How do we go from the first equation to the second?

Comment: Maybe contraposition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $F_0$ means $\bot$ (the always [False logical constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_(logic))), we can easily check (with truth table) that [$p \to F_0$ is equivalent to $\lnot p$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_(logic)#False,_negation_and_contradiction): due to the fact that $F_0$ is always False, we have only two cases: $\text T → \text F$ and $\text F → \text F$, and the result is exactly the opposite of $p$.

Thus, $\lnot p \to F_0$ is $\lnot \lnot p$ that, in classical logic, is equivalent to $p$.

---

For the same reason, $(p_i \land \lnot q) \to F_0$ is equivalent to $\lnot (p_i \land \lnot q)$ which is in turn equivalent to $p_i \to \lnot \lnot q$.

Comment: Just so I understand the first point: p-> F_0 means when p is true, F_0 is false and when p is False, F_0 is true. Thus, since F_0 is the opposite of p, this overall statement (p->F_0) is equivalent to -p ?

Comment: @user162264 - NO; $F_0$ is **ALWAYS** False. Thus we have only two cases $T \to F$ and $F \to F$. Compute them...